# Unable to read local SQL Server file when running as exe. Works in IDE

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the first time that I am trying to use a SQL Server File type database. It works when I run in the IDE but when I double click on the exe or right mouse click "Run Elevated," I get an error when trying to connect.

The message box displays the same connection string when running in both modes.

What might be the issue? Some sort of permissions issue?

```
MessageBox.Show(ApplicationParameter.LocalDatabaseConnectionString);
databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ApplicationParameter.LocalDatabaseConnectionString);
databaseConnection.Open();
```

I get the following SqlException:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

Here is the connectionstring from the app.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="LocalDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\MYCODE\MyCompany.DISKMONITOR\MyCompany.DISKMONITOR\DATA\DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

And my class for reading the app config:

```
class ApplicationParameter
    {

        public static string LocalDatabaseConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Update:**

I ran as Administrator and got the same result.

Comment: Whats the exception message and exception type?

Comment: Are you supposed to have `...\MyCompany.DISKMONITOR\MyCompany.DISKMONITOR\...` in the path?

Comment: please refresh the updated question.

Comment: which account is your exe running under? If running from VS IDE, the exe is running under admin privilege.

Comment: @Matt VS only runs programs with admin if it, itself, is ran as administrator. That's an extra step that most people wouldn't take.

Comment: Same result when I run as Admin

Comment: can you check event log to see if there're some details about the error?

Comment: Sql Server requires an installation of the Sql Server service already be running on your system. It's meant more for shared databases running on dedicated servers, and it's really a poor choice most of the time for use as a local data store.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean when saying "Works in IDE"?  What exactly works?  Is it that you are able to query the file in VS? or do you mean that you have some other app?

Comment: Your connection string is missing the final semi-colon (;) at the end. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ Also, if the database is inside of your project, then change its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer"

Comment: @Andrew: Adding a semi colon didn't change the result. Regarding your comment about "Copy to Output directory," does this suggest that I need a reference to the mdf and/or ldf file? I'm thinking that one cannot set a reference to these files and so this option would not apply. Besides, I fully qualify the location of the mdf in teh connectionstring...:-)

Comment: @ChadD I would just build out the connection into a class file. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @Joel: I would agree with your comment if I were not using the *File* version of SQL Server. My expectations was that this was a light weight alternative local database that would not require anything other that the .NET FW to be installed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ChadD Do you mean Sql Server **Compact** Edition? There is no such thing as the File version of Sql Server. Compact Edition is the closest, and it does work the way you want. However, Compact Edition uses *.sdf files, not *.mdf files, and your connection string is for a full Sql Server version. Express Edition of Sql Server is still the full server.

Answer (score 0):

Connections.Classified contains information specific to the location of the db, what instance to use and username/password information. Will not be posted...

Here is my SQLConnections.cs class that I use in all of my apps (well mine is oracle I've just updated it to work with SQL):

```
private String connectionString = "Server=" + SERVER + "\\" + INSTANCE + ";Database=" + DATABASE + ";User Id="+ USER + ";Password=" + PASSWORD + ";"

protected SQLConnection getConnection()
{
    return new SQLConnection(connectionString);
}
```

In use in a repo class that extends the Connections.SQLConnections:

```
SQLConnection connection = getConnection();
```

A lot less clutter and easier for someone else, reading your code, to understand.

Comment: Please note that my conenction string specifies Integrated Security=True" so a user code password is not required. Again, I am using a *file based* Database, not the usual SQL Server instance where you would specify a server name or (local).

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpetting what file based databases are or confuising uit with compact databases. I expected that this was an alterantive to using a full blown instance that requires a service.

Comment: Ya that is weird, if it works in testing, on publish it should work as well. That's why I asked if the database was in the project and to set it as Copy if newer, that allows the db to be published with the project. I have to do that for images and other resources.

Comment: I placed my mdf in a subfolder of the app but didn't  include it in teh project. When I did, I had theoption to "Copy Newer". However,now I am struggling with trying to create a click once package. I was expecting that I should just be able to double click on the exe and forgo the deployment since it is a program that only I will run. I am not clear about the difference bwteen atatching to an mdf and specifying a server. perhaps i wanted a Compact db instead to not be dependent on SQL Server being installed